# How to open a excel file with several sheets as one single dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have an excel file with 10 sheets, every one of these 10 sheets has the name of the respondent, like> `sheet1-Andres`, `sheet2-Paul` and so  on...

The **columns's header are the same for all sheets** also the questions.  The only difference is how each respondent fill `Answers A` to `Answers Z` with **zero** and **ones**

```
Question        Answer A   Answer B   Answer C
question 1        1          0          0
question 2        0          1          1
question 3        0          0          1
```

As the excel file has 10 sheets, I am looking for a way to open this `xlsx` file as a dataframe using Pandas but as **one single dataframe** in a way that I can after load it make some calculations, like:

```
How many `1` and `zeros` the Answer A got considering all the 10 respondents.
```

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass `None` to the `sheet_name` argument and then reset the index after a concat.

```
df = pd.concat(
      pd.read_excel('your_file', sheet_name=None)
              ).reset_index(0).rename(columns={'level_0':'names'})


df['names'] = df1["names"].str.replace("sheet\d{1}-", "", regex=True).str.strip()
```

---

```
print(df)

     names    Question  Answer 1  Answer 2  Answer 3
0  Andreas  question-1       1.0       0.0       1.0
1  Andreas  question-2       0.0       1.0       0.0
2  Andreas  question-3       1.0       1.0       1.0
0     Paul  question-1       1.0       0.0       1.0
1     Paul  question-2       0.0       1.0       0.0
2     Paul  question-3       1.0       1.0       1.0
```